# How to execute function for each observable in RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

I have a situation with observable like this:

```
//pseudo code
var agreement:Observable<agreement[]> = Observable.ajax({...})
    .flatMap(agreements:[] => {
        agreements.forEach(agreement =>{
           //server request for each agreement
           //If request fail throw exception
        });
        return agreements;
    })
    .map(agreements => agreements);
```

Here, I need to check each agreement if it`s exist in other server and throw exception if not. Main question is how wait while all all agreements are checked adn only then get result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this depends on what's happening inside the `forEach` loop – if `agreements` (the one going into the `flatMap`) is an Observable that you're using `forEach` to emit, the strategy is a bit different altogether because you don't necessarily know how many `agreement` objects will be emitted.

Assuming though the `forEach` is just running some other basic http calling, say, one that returns promises... The answer is then going to involve collecting the promises and allowing them all to complete the *Promise-way*, so that the completion can then be converted into an Observable for the next operator in the chain.

Some pseudo code:

```
var agreement: Observable<agreement[]> = Observable.ajax({...})
    .flatMap(agreements:[] => {
        const promises = agreements.map(agreement => doHttpThing()
            .then(...)
            .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
        );
        return Observable.fromPromise(Promise.all(promises));
    })
    .map(agreements => agreements);
```